# Microsoft Graph Mail create subscription: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The requested user is invalid.]

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to create a subscription to email receipt using Microsoft Graph API.

### My setup

I tried using the node API, following the [tutorial on their Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample)

I also tried by hand, using postman to send a post request and manually getting the token, then setting up a server for the challenge.

### The error

For both, I receive the following error:

> Error: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The requested user '85601dde-359a-4eae-a91e-a0f18a645ba4@9118c136-2fff-45b0-9695-dac64c966630' is invalid.]

### Incomprehension

I don't really understand is "85601dde-359a-4eae-a91e-a0f18a645ba4@9118c136-2fff-45b0-9695-dac64c966630" because I saw in other posts that people have their email address in this error. I can find this ids in the JWT token so I guess that's where it comes from but I don't know if it's normal.

I also found that the issue might be that I have a "on premises mail" and not an "Office 365 mail" but I was confirmed that I have a Office 365 mail.

### Details

My authorizations are:

- `Mail.Read` (of type application)
- `User.Read` (of type delegated)

And here is my payload:

```
{
  "changeType": "created",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState",
  "notificationUrl": "https://e0a2d0f478cf.ngrok.io",
  "resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-11-28T04:30:28.2257768+00:00"
}
```

### Complete error response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The requested user '85601dde-359a-4eae-a91e-a0f18a645ba4@9118c136-2fff-45b0-9695-dac64c966630' is invalid.]",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-27T12:24:08",
            "request-id": "227dd9a1-858f-4286-b1b3-a22d2d0d8529",
            "client-request-id": "227dd9a1-858f-4286-b1b3-a22d2d0d8529"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the requestid and timestamp for the failed request.

Comment: Thank you for take a look, I added a "Complete error response", I think their is what you want. Please ask me if you need something else

Comment: Looks like you are using Client Credential flow and getting the token and then making a POST request. So try modifying resource as 'users/{userid}/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages'. If you want to use me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages use delegated permission(Mail.read) and get the user token.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: This would make sense. Since I'm setting up something to be executed by a server I must use 'users/{userid}/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages'.
I'm just trying to figure out how to get the userid and I'll let you know if it works, thank again for your help

Comment: You can just use /Users/UPN in postman and get the id and test it.

Comment: Yeah I just did and it seems to be working ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad to here that it resolves your issue :)-

Comment: Do you want to write an answer that I can validate in order to help others who might have this issue? I've been struggling for 2 days so you really saved me here ! :)

Comment: Feeling Happy for you as it got resolved finally :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Client Credential flow and getting the token and then making a POST request. So try modifying resource as

`users/{userid}/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages`

If you want to use me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages use delegated permission(Mail.read) and get the user token.